# Hide Base Templates in Mosaico?

Tags: civimail, mosaico

now that mosaico has 3 base templates for people to choose from - we don't want our users choosing any of those and only want them to use the custom template we created. Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this now is to go to **Administer menu » CiviMail » Mosaico Settings** and configure the *Hide these base templates* option. See screenshot.

[image: CiviCRM Mosaico setttings]

Answer (score 4):

I think there is nothing that allow to hide base templates for now.

Personally, I would like to see a functionality that allows hide selectively the usable templates from a list of available templates. Perhaps a new featured request could be opened on https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico on this direction.

Comment: Featured request has been opened on https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/241. Good job @themak!

Answer (score 3):

We did it by just removing those template files from the server (I couldn't find a less brute-force way to do it).  In wordpress they are here:  `wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates`.

Comment: Hi Ruth, I removed the base templates, but that led to no templates being available for use.  Could you clarify who exactly you removed them from the server.

Comment: Hi themak, I didn't delete any templates until I had used the versafix-1 template to create a custom template for my organization.  Even then, I didn't delete the original versafix-1, I only deleted the tedc15 template which we were never going to use.  IDK what would happen if I now deleted the original versafix - would my customized template go away too??  Don't really want to try it...